# org.springframework.core.env.Environment.getProperty(String) returns null

Tags: spring, configuration, properties

I am trying to access some properties programmatically in a controller of a spring mvc application. I configured it by xml. I tried both `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and `<context:property-placeholder />`

I tried to use in the controller class(saw it in a working example but it was configured with `@Configuration`):

```
@Inject  
private Environment environment;
```

and afterwards i use:

```
environment.getProperty("upload.location")
```

but i get a null value. The entry exists in the properties file(i have only one) and also using `${...}` in the xml works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much simpler way - use `@Value` to inject the system property, as follows:

```
private @Value("${systemPropertyFoo}") String systemPropertyFoo;
```

In your case (I"m assuming the variable is a system property):

```
private @Value("${upload.location}") String uploadLocation;
```

This annotation depends on the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, so keep it in your config.